# jQuery ready() in asp.net mvc2 only fires on first visit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Hello jQuery.");
});
</script>
```

This works the first time I request `/Home/Index`, but if I navigate to eg `/Account/Login` then back to `/Home/Index` it doesn't work. Doing the same thing using a webforms project works every time. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Is there some other javascript error happening on the page?  Check your console to make sure that isn't the case.

Comment: where is this scrip?, master page | /Home/Index.aspx ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.  The answer, and a question: The relative reference to the .js files was OK for `http: //localhost:12345/` but not `http: //localhost:12345/Home/Index` - effectively they're the same resource, but not internally for mvc, despite the fact the mvc "paths" are logical not physical - so why does mvc make .js references relative to a logical path?

Answer (score 0):

this is not the answer. try this:

```
<div id="test-ready"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#test-ready").append("<span>pre ready</span><br />");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test-ready").append("<span>in ready (hello jQuery)</span><br />");
            //alert("Hello jQuery.");
        });
        $("#test-ready").append("<span>pos ready</span><br />");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    alert("Hello jQuery.");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Maybe it will give you less trouble.

Comment: that is the same thing really, just another way of saying it.

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes just changing the way you say the same thing helps.  That's why it figured a "maybe".